# Can't get ethernet adapter to work on centos 7.9, I tried both Realtek RTL8125 and Intel I225V

Tags: centos, network-interface, ethernet

I just installed Centos7 on a desktop computer because I need this specific OS for compatibility with CAD software that I am using. The installation went fine but my internet isn't working. I researched things a bit:

Output of `ifconfig -a` doesn't show network cards and only shows: `lo`, `virbr0` and `virbr0-nic`.

So I ran `lshw -c network`, and I can see my network cards with status `*-network UNCLAIMED`. Specifically, they are:

- Intel(R) Ethernet Controller I225V
- Realtek RTL8125 2.5 GbE Controller -- I bought this one after failing to get the Intel one to work :(

So I did some more research online, basically I just need to install the driver, right? So I went to elrepo [here](https://elrepo.org/linux/elrepo/el7/x86_64/RPMS/) and I installed the following two packages:

For

- Intel, I tried: `kmod-ixgbe-5.12.5-2.el7_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm`
- For Realtek, I tried: `kmod-r8125-9.009.02-1.el7_9.elrepo.x86_64.rpm`

I really thought the latter would work, especially when I found [threads online with the same problem, and the solution was simply to install this driver](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=75891). I now have literally no idea what to try next. The network card green light is flashing but I am unable to get it to work? Am I missing something? Is this the wrong driver? Any ideas for debugging are most appreciated.

Note lspci -n gives me the following codes for the two devices:

- Intel: 8086:15f3
- Realtek: 10ec:8125

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the solution.

My machine had "secure boot" turned on which rejects any third-party drivers. I turned it off by using the following command, and as described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules).

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Answer (score 0):

I225 Series is not supported in CentOS 7.9 and would require their `igc` driver to be available for Linux download for recompile.

See Intel OS Support page: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000055236/ethernet-products/gigabit-ethernet-controllers-up-to-2-5gbe.html

best bet is to switch to a compatible NIC