# Unable to get Intel I225-IT drivers for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, drivers, network-interface, intel

Is anyone able to get intel drivers for the Intel I225 series to work on CentOS 7 (7.9 to be exact)?

Intel seems to not have the `igc` drives available for download from intel to even build.

A vendor switch NICs without telling and trying to get this to work.

Believe I might just be stuck having to track down and replace the NIC with an I210.  Or download kernel source for the driver but that seems messy and a maintenance pain, along with trying to get it working on 3.10 that CentOS 7 is on.

[Similar problem on question 721948](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/721948/cant-get-ethernet-adapter-to-work-on-centos-7-9-i-tried-both-realtek-rtl8125-a) but a switch out was the main fix of the original I225-V (which would use the same driver I need).

I think I've answered my own question, but just trying to find out if anyone else was able to get this working?

Comment: Can you Check If this works https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/38350-intel-ethernet-controller-i225-v-solved/